# Visual basic .NET - Show the number of days in the selected month

Tags: vb.net

i'm brand new to VB and i'd like to create a program that: when i input the number of the month (in a input box) it tells me how many days there's is in that month and if i input a incorrect month it tells me "error".

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim months As String
        months = InputBox("What is the number of the month?", "Months", , , )

    End Sub
End Class
```

[Program so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE6Zu.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [DateTime.DaysInMonth()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth?view=netframework-4.8).

You'll need to parse the user's input into an Integer with `Int32.TryParse()`, then pass the resultant Integer to `DaysInMonth()`, along with the current year which can be accessed via `DateTime.Now.Year`

Example:

```
Dim userMonth As String
' Prompt the user to enter the month and assign it to userMonth.

Dim iMonth As Integer = 0
If Int32.TryParse(userMonth, iMonth) AndAlso (iMonth >= 1 And iMonth <= 12) Then
   Dim iDaysInMonth As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, iMonth)
   Dim sMonthName As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.MonthName(iMonth)
   MessageBox.Show($"Days in month {sMonthName}: {iDaysInMonth}")
Else
   MessageBox.Show($"Invalid month specified: {userMonth}", "Error")
End If
```

You could also not check the value of `iMonth` and wrap the `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` call in a try/catch block, since it will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if `iMonth` is invalid.